# Fresh herbs going bad

Tags: food-preservation, herbs, fresh

When I buy fresh herbs from the grocery store they go bad too quickly what can I do to keep them fresher longer?

I just bought a vacuum sealer because I thought it would help preserve my food longer.

Should I seal and freeze or can they be kept in the frig?

Comment: It's almost a duplicate but IMHO the part about using a vacuum sealer warrants leaving it open. That said, Donna, have you checked the other question?